# tensorflow hessians - RunTimeError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to understand tensorflow 2.0 hessians. I understand the math part of it, but I am trying to understand the code part of it.

The toy code I have is as follows-

```
a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([1, 1, 2], dtype=tf.float32)                            
tf.hessians(a, b)
```

This gives-

> RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is
>   enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.

What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: So a is not dependent on b by any means. Not sure what you expect by trying to compute derivatives of a w.r.t. b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you want to achieve,

`tf.hessians` adds a TensorFlow op to the graph to compute the hessian. Therefore, if you want to use hessian, you have to call that within a function decorated with `tf.function` as follows. Using `tf.hessian` without `tf.function` decorator tries to execute this without building the graph (in Eager mode). This will not work, thus end up an error.

And most importantly, your `b` needs to depend on `a`. Note I'm computing `d2b/d2a`. Otherwise, you get the following.

> ValueError: Tried to convert 'tensor' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.

```
a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)

@tf.function
def compute_b(a):
  b = a**2
  hes = tf.hessians(b, a)
  return b, hes


b, d2y_d2x = compute_b(a)
print(d2y_d2x)
```